# What are the different names of God in the Bible and what do they mean?

Tags: bible, names-of-god

I see that our current-day Bibles only refer to God as LORD.  Can you explain to me what the different names of God are and what they mean?

Comment: Wow, there are so many.  You may want to be more specific.  Do you want the Hebrew names, the translated versions of Hebrew names, or the 'purely' English names?

Comment: I have no idea how many that there are. You might start by explaining each name is it was originally written.

Comment: See also: [Is God's name Yahweh or Jehovah?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1630/914)

Comment: You may wanna ask [these guys](https://www.facebook.com/HolyNameSociety).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Elohim

Genesis 1:1 (ESV)

> <sup>**1**</sup>
> In the beginning, God [Elohim] created the heavens and the earth.

Pslam 19:1 (ESV)

> <sup>**1**</sup> The heavens declare the glory of God, [Elohim]
>    and the sky above proclaims his handiwork.

The name "Elohim" means "God" and is a reference to God's power and might.

### Adonai

Malachi  1:6 (ESV)

> … And if I am a master, where is my fear? says the LORD of hosts [Adonai] to you, O priests…

Adonai means "Lord" and refers to the Lordship of God.

### Jehovah/Yahweh

Genesis 2:4 (ESV)

> <sup>**4**</sup>  These are the generations of the heavens and the earth when they were created,in the day that the LORD God [Jehovah-Yahweh] made the earth and the heavens.

Translated as *I am*, *I am who am*, or *I am who I am*, and indicates God's personal, eternal, non-contingent nature. It is given to Moses *by God* when prompted for His name.

### Jehovah-Maccaddeshem

Exodus 31:13

> <sup>**13**</sup>"You are to speak to the people of Israel and say, 'Above all you shall keep my Sabbaths, for this is a sign between me and you throughout your generations, that you may know that I, the LORD, [Jehovah-Maccaddeshem] sanctify you.'"

Means "The Lord thy sanctifier"

### Jehovah-Rohi

Psalm 23:1 (ESV)

> <sup>**1**</sup>The LORD [Jehovah-Rohi] is my shepherd; I shall not want.

### Jehovah-Shammah

Ezekiel 48:35 (ESV)

> <sup>**35**</sup>The circumference of the city shall be 18,000 cubits. And the name of the city from that time on shall be, The LORD Is There. [Jehovah-Shammah]"

Means "The Lord who is present"

### Jehovah-Rapha

Exodus 15:26 (ESV)

> "…I will put none of the diseases on you that I put on the Egyptians, for I am the LORD, your healer. [Jehovah-Rapha]"

Means "The Lord our healer"

### Jehovah-Tsidkenu

Jeremiah 23:6 (ESV)

> <sup>**6**</sup>In his days Judah will be saved, and Israel will dwell securely. And this is the name by which he will be called: 'The LORD is our righteousness.'

Means "The Lord our righteousness"

### Jehovah-Jireh

Genesis 22:14 (ESV)

> <sup>**14**</sup>So Abraham called the name of that place, "The LORD will provide"; as it is said to this day, "On the mount of the LORD it shall be provided."

Means "The Lord will provide"

### Jehovah-Nissi

Exodus 17:15 (ESV)

> <sup>**15**</sup>And Moses built an altar and called the name of it, The LORD Is My Banner,

Means the "The Lord is my banner"

### Jehovah-Shalom

Judges 6:24 (ESV)

> <sup>**24**</sup>Then Gideon built an altar there to the LORD [Jehovah-Shalom] and called it, The LORD Is Peace. To this day it still stands at Ophrah, which belongs to the Abiezrites.

Means "The Lord is peace"

### Jehovah-Sabbaoth

Isaiah 6:1-3 (ESV)

> <sup>**3**</sup>And one called to another and said:
>
>        "Holy, holy, holy is the LORD of hosts; the whole earth is full of his glory!"

Means the "Lord of hosts"

### Jehovah-Gmolah

Jeremiah 51:6 (ESV)

> <sup>**6**</sup>
> …Be not cut off in her punishment,               for this is the time of the LORD’s [Jehovah-Gmolah] vengeance,                the repayment he is rendering her.

Means "The God of Recompense"

### El-Elyon

Genesis 14:17-20 (ESV)

> <sup>**19**</sup>And he blessed him and said,
>
>        "Blessed be Abram by God Most High,
>        Possessor[a] of heaven and earth;
> <sup>**20**</sup>and blessed be God Most High,
>       who has delivered your enemies into your hand!"

Isaiah 14:14 (ESV)

> <sup>**14**</sup>I will ascend above the heights of the clouds;
>     I will make myself like the Most High.'

Means "The most high God"

### El-Roi

Genesis 16:13 (ESV)

> <sup>**13**</sup> So she called the name of the LORD [El-Roi] who spoke to her, "You are a God of seeing," for she said, "Truly here I have seen him who looks after me."

Means "The strong one who sees"

### El-Shaddai

Genesis 17:1 (ESV)

> <sup>**1**</sup>
> When Abram was ninety-nine years old the LORD appeared to Abram and said to him, "I am God Almighty [El Shaddai]; walk before me, and be blameless,

Psalm 91:1

> <sup>**1**</sup> He who dwells in the shelter of the Most High [El-Shaddai]
>    will abide in the shadow of the Almighty.

Means "The God of the mountains" or "God Almighty"

### El-Olam

Isaiah 40:31 (ESV)

> <sup>**31**</sup>but they who wait for the LORD shall renew their strength; 
>      they shall mount up with wings like eagles;
> they shall run and not be weary;
>      they shall walk and not faint.

Means "The everlasting God"

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here are some other names of God:

```
•   ABBA.............................Romans 8:15
•   ADVOCATE.........................I John 2:1 (kjv)
•   ALMIGHTY.........................Genesis 17:1
•   ALPHA............................Revelation 22:13
•   AMEN.............................Revelation 3:14
•   ANCIENT OF DAYS..................Daniel 7:9
•   ANOINTED ONE.....................Psalm 2:2
•   APOSTLE..........................Hebrews 3:1
•   ARM OF THE LORD..................Isaiah 53:1
•   AUTHOR OF LIFE...................Acts 3:15
•   AUTHOR OF OUR FAITH..............Hebrews 12:2

•   BEGINNING.........................Revelation 21:6
•   BLESSED & HOLY RULER..............1 Timothy 6:15
•   BRANCH............................Jeremiah 33:15
•   BREAD OF GOD......................John 6:33
•   BREAD OF LIFE.....................John 6:35
•   BRIDEGROOM........................Isaiah 62:56
•   BRIGHT MORNING STAR...............Revelation 22:16

•   CHIEF SHEPHERD.....................1 Peter 5:4
•   CHOSEN ONE.........................Isaiah 42:1
•   CHRIST.............................Matthew 22:42
•   CHRIST OF GOD......................Luke 9:20
•   CHRIST THE LORD....................Luke 2:11
•   CHRIST, SON OF LIVING GOD..........Matthew 16:16
•   COMFORTER..........................John 14:26(kjv)
•   COMMANDER..........................Isaiah 55:4
•   CONSOLATION OF ISRAEL...............Luke 2:25
•   CONSUMING FIRE......................Deut. 4:24, Heb. 12:29
•   CORNERSTONE.........................Isaiah 28:16
•   COUNSELOR...........................Isaiah 9:6
•   CREATOR.............................1 Peter 4:19

•   DELIVERER..............................Romans 11:26
•   DESIRED OF ALL NATIONS.................Haggai 2:7
•   DOOR...................................John 10:7(kjv)

•   END....................................Revelation 21:6
•   ETERNAL GOD............................Deut. 33:27
•   EVERLASTING FATHER.....................Isaiah 9:6

•   FAITHFUL & TRUE........................Revelation 19:11
•   FAITHFUL WITNESS.......................Revelation 1:5
•   FATHER.................................Matthew 6:9
•   FIRSTBORN (3)........................................Rom.8:29,Rev.1:5,Col.1:15
•   FIRSTFRUITS............................1 Cor.15:20-23
•   FOUNDATION.............................1 Cor. 3:11
•   FRIEND OF TAX COLLECTORS & SINNERS.....Matthew 11:19

•   GENTLE WHISPER.........................1 Kings 19:12
•   GIFT OF GOD............................John 4:10
•   GLORY OF THE LORD......................Isaiah 40:5
•   GOD....................................Genesis 1:1
•   GOD ALMIGHTY...........................Genesis 17:1
•   GOD OVER ALL...........................Romans 9:5
•   GOD WHO SEES ME........................Genesis 16:13
•   GOOD SHEPHERD..........................John 10:11
•   GREAT HIGH PRIEST......................Hebrews 4:14
•   GREAT SHEPHERD.........................Hebrews 13:20
•   GUIDE..................................Psalm 48:14

•   HEAD OF THE BODY.......................Colossians 1:18
•   HEAD OF THE CHURCH.....................Ephesians 5:23
•   HEIR OF ALL THINGS.....................Hebrews 1:2
•   HIGH PRIEST............................Hebrews 3:1
•   HIGH PRIEST FOREVER....................Hebrews 6:20
•   HOLY ONE...............................Acts 2:27
•   HOLY ONE OF ISRAEL.....................Isaiah 49:7
•   HOLY SPIRIT............................John 15:26
•   HOPE...................................Titus 2:13
•   HORN OF SALVATION......................Luke 1:69

•   I AM....................................Exodus 3:14, John 8:58
•   IMAGE OF GOD............................2 Cor. 4:4
•   IMAGE OF HIS PERSON.....................Hebrews 1:3 (kjv)
•   IMMANUEL................................Isaiah 7:14

•   JEALOUS..............................Exodus 34:14 (kjv)
•   JEHOVAH..............................Psalm 83:18 (kjv)
•   JESUS................................Matthew 1:21
•   JESUS CHRIST OUR LORD................Romans 6:23
•   JUDGE................................Isaiah 33:22, Acts 10:42

•   KING.................................Zechariah 9:9
•   KING ETERNAL.........................1 Timothy 1:17
•   KING OF KINGS........................1 Timothy 6:15
•   KING OF THE AGES.....................Revelation 15:3

•   LAMB OF GOD...........................John 1:29
•   LAST ADAM.............................1 Cor. 15:45
•   LAWGIVER..............................Isaiah 33:22
•   LEADER................................Isaiah 55:4
•   LIFE..................................John 14:6
•   LIGHT OF THE WORLD....................John 8:12
•   LIKE AN EAGLE.........................Deut. 32:11
•   LILY OF THE VALLEYS...................Song 2:1
•   LION OF THE TRIBE OF JUDAH............Revelation 5:5
•   LIVING STONE..........................1 Peter 2:4
•   LIVING WATER..........................John 4:10
•   LORD..................................John 13:13
•   LORD GOD ALMIGHTY.....................Revelation 15:3
•   LORD JESUS CHRIST.....................1 Cor. 15:57
•   LORD OF ALL...........................Acts 10:36
•   LORD OF GLORY ........................1 Cor. 2:8
•   LORD OF HOSTS.........................Haggai 1:5
•   LORD OF LORDS.........................1 Tim. 6:15
•   LORD OUR RIGHTEOUSNESS..............Jeremiah 23:6
•   LOVE.................................1 John 4:8

•   MAN OF SORROWS.........................Isaiah 53:3
•   MASTER..................................Luke 5:5
•   MEDIATOR................................1 Timothy 2:5
•   MERCIFUL GOD............................Jeremiah 3:12
•   MESSENGER OF THE COVENANT................Malachi 3:1
•   MESSIAH................................. John 4:25
•   MIGHTY GOD...............................Isaiah 9:6
•   MIGHTY ONE...............................Isaiah 60:16

•   NAZARENE.................................Matthew 2:23

•   OFFSPRING OF DAVID.......................Revelation 22:16
•   OMEGA....................................Revelation 22:13
•   ONLY BEGOTTEN SON........................John 1:18(kjv)
•   OUR PASSOVER LAMB........................1 Cor. 5:7
•   OUR PEACE................................Ephesians 2:14

•   POTTER...................................Isaiah 64:8
•   POWER OF GOD.............................1 Cor. 1:24
•   PRINCE OF PEACE..........................Isaiah 9:6
•   PROPHET..................................Acts 3:22
•   PURIFIER.................................Malachi 3:3

•   RABBONI (TEACHER)........................John 20:16
•   RADIANCE OF GOD'S GLORY..................Heb.1:3
•   REDEEMER.................................Job 19:25
•   REFINER'S FIRE...........................Malachi 3:2
•   RESURRECTION.............................John 11:25
•   RIGHTEOUS ONE............................1 John 2:1
•   ROCK.....................................1 Cor.10:4
•   ROOT OF DAVID............................Rev. 22:16
•   ROSE OF SHARON...........................Song 2:1
•   RULER OF GOD'S CREATION..................Rev. 3:14
•   RULER OVER KINGS OF EARTH................Rev 1:5
•   RULER OVER ISRAEL........................Micah 5:2

•   SAVIOR...................................Luke 2:11
•   SCEPTER OUT OF ISRAEL....................Numbers 24:17
•   SEED.....................................Genesis 3:15
•   SERVANT..................................Isaiah 42:1
•   SHEPHERD OF OUR SOULS....................1Peter 2:25
•   SHIELD...................................Genesis 15:1
•   SON OF DAVID.............................Matthew 1:1
•   SON OF GOD...............................Matthew 27:54
•   SON OF MAN...............................Matthew 8:20
•   SON OF THE MOST HIGH.....................Luke 1:32
•   SOURCE...................................Hebrews 5:9
•   SPIRIT OF GOD............................Genesis 1:2
•   STAR OUT OF JACOB........................Numbers 24:17
•   STONE....................................1 Peter 2:8
•   SUN OF RIGHTEOUSNESS.....................Malachi 4:2

•   TEACHER...................................John 13:13
•   TRUE LIGHT................................John 1:9
•   TRUE WITNESS..............................Revelation 3:14
•   TRUTH.....................................John 14:6

•   VINE......................................John 15:5

•   WAY........................................John 14:6
•   WISDOM OF GOD..............................1 Cor. 1:24
•   WITNESS....................................Isaiah 55:4
•   WONDERFUL..................................Isaiah 9:6
•   WORD.......................................John 1:1
•   WORD OF GOD................................Revelation 19:13
```

Comment: The Malachi verse is Jehovah-Sabbaoth, not Adonai.

Comment: You say that Elohim means "God"; what do you make of men who are referred to as elohim?

Comment: @Ray Men who are referred to as elohim? I don't get it...

Comment: See, e.g., Ps 82:6 and John 10:34-50 (which references and expands on the former)

Comment: @Ray Ah, I see what you mean. Elohim in those verses refers to gods. See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elohim_(gods)#Canaanite_religion). So, depending on your translation (I have ESV), it will read elohim or gods.

Comment: One of the names is JEALOUS. Jealous of what?

Comment: @Ray, they are *elohim* according to their office, not their nature.

Comment: @Meysam, The archaic meaning of *jealous* is Hebrew for **qannah**, "possessing sensitive and deep feelings."

Comment: @Meysam:  By JEALOUS, the Bible is not talking about some petty and unfounded emotion that a suspicious husband has when for no good reason he becomes jealous of his wife's supposed paramour. No, God said clearly in the Big Ten, "You shall have no other gods before me," meaning that He will brook no competition from lesser gods and idols, the former of which do not exist, and the latter of which (e.g., money, possessions, power, fame, security, pleasure) will one day pass away.  Makes sense to me. If God is indeed El Elyon, God Most High, no one and nothing can rise above the MOST HIGH.

Comment: Ditto @rhetorician *thumbs up for a good explanation*

Comment: @daviesgeek, Isn't Elohim an epithet meaning "mighty"? As such, why do you say  "Elohim" means "God" in the first paragraph?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, it is *similar* to an epithet, but the actual definition is "God", with a reference to the mighty power of God. Not that Wikipedia is the best source, but: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elohim

Comment: Elohim was God before creation. The meaning of the word "God" means Object of worship. Since there was no existence of anyone/anything to worship Him He was the Elohim. Elohim became God when the angels were created.

Comment: God's primary name is 'Holy'. All other names of God are secondary to that name.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi -- I disagree with you. The word "God" does not *define* God, as you imply.  For God was God before the Angels existed.  Your word "God" must fit *that* definition.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start by understanding where the usage of LORD came.  LORD is Jehovah, which is Yahweh (YHWH), the ineffable name of the God of Israel.  (This is why Jewish people sometimes write G-d.)

Start with the Wikipedia article on Jehova. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah

Under the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah#Introduction_into_English section, it says "The Authorized King James Bible also, which used Jehovah in a few places, most frequently gave 'the LORD' as the equivalent of the Tetragammaton."

(The Tetragammaton is YHWH.)

PS:  My favorite name is 'the LORD of heavens armies' or 'the LORD of hosts'.   (The God of Israel is also nice as it is very specific.)

Comment: "The Lord of the heavens' armies" not a proper name its a title like "General of the Fifth Army Division" or 'King of Rock and Roll'. But Jehovah is God's proper name like Douglas McArthur or Elvis Presley.

Comment: @LemuelAdane: The distinction between names and titles isn't really that black and white. In many languages there is actually no difference, people's titles often become their names and vise versa. "The LORD of hosts" can be a name, and in many cases God chooses to introduce himself to and be known by the people using a title rather than a name.

Answer (score 1):

HERE ARE SOME OTHER NAMES OF GOD

JANELLE - GOD IS GRACIOUS

THOR - THY MAKER

ABBA - FATHER

ALPHA & OMEGA - THE BEGINNING & END

IMMANUEL - GOD WITH US

Comment: Can you include Bible references for where these names are found in the Bible?

Comment: Why is everything in upper case?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the proper noun name of God, then there is only one name. Some of the said above are titles, except for one name JEHOVAH. When Moises ask God what is his name God said in Exodus 3:15, Then God said once more to Moses: “This is what you are to say to the sons of Israel, Jehovah the God of your forefathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac and the God of Jacob, has sent me to you.’ This is my name to time indefinite, and this is the memorial of me to generation after generation - Exodus 3:15 (New World Translation) So God has only one personal name, like you, you have only one personal name.

Below are some verses which are proof that God's proper noun name is Jehovah:

That men may know that thou, whose name alone is JEHOVAH, art the most high over all the earth. Psalm 83:18 (King James Version)

Behold, God is my salvation; I will trust, and not be afraid: for the LORD JEHOVAH is my strength and my song; he also is become my salvation.
Isaiah 12:2 (King James Version)

Trust ye in the LORD for ever: for in the LORD JEHOVAH is everlasting strength:
Isaiah 26:4 (King James Version)

For more information read [The Divine Name that Will Endure Forever.](http://www.watchtower.org/e/na/index.htm)

Comment: How to Jehovah Witnesses defend this particular rendering of the name in light of the fact that the original Hebrew vowels for this word are not known? Also how do they interpret Isaiah 9:6 "_For to us a child is born, to us a son is given; and the government shall be upon his shoulder, and his name shall be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace._" Are these not also names by which he shall be known?

Comment: @ Caleb. You said you are "scripting language connoisseur, regular expression aficionado, network geek, general lover of Linux and a frequent contributor to open source software." Which of those "names" you write in a paper that ask of your name, or do you put there "Caleb Maclenan"? Its the same with God and his personal name is Jehovah, though he has many titles like "Elohim" or "Adonai." but his personal name is Jehovah.

Comment: @ Caleb. Will you restrain your child from calling your name because the child cannot describe your name perfectly? I know you wont do that, instead you will be happy for that because the child recognizes you. Same with Jehovah, he is happy for the people recognizing, hollowing his name everyday, not constraint by traditional misconceptions about the renditions of his name.

Comment: @LemuelAdane The vocalization Jehova has no biblical support, and as best we can tell originated in 1100ad. YHWH is the transliteration of how it actually appears in the those passages. The vowel sounds are not known as they Jews avoided pronouncing His proper name aloud. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehova

Answer (score -1):

The name of god is rendered in English Jehovah. We do not know that that is exactly how it is pronounced. Your name in your language is familiar to you, but yet when you hear your name in another language it will sometimes sound very alien.

I don't expect a foreign person to be able to pronounce my name correctly. In fact most do not. I am very pleased when someone remembers my name and uses it. It shows me that they cared enough or where interested enough in me to remember my name.

Here is another example. The bible tells us that god wants us to know both his name and the qualities attached to it. Say then that we know the president, but we don't know his name. Knowing the job of the president doesn't help us to understand the man behind the position. We don't know him as a person, only that he is our leader and generally what he is supposed to do.

As for gods name, in the exodus when Moses asked god what he should call him god answered  “I shall prove to be what I shall prove to be.” (Exodus 3:14). In other words that means he will become whatever I need to become.

The jews stopped using gods name because of superstitious reasons. God commanded them not to take up his name in a worthless way. Today most bible translations have taken that same aspect of substituting Jehovah's name for Lord and god. Like the president those are just titles and don't allow us to truly identify the traits of god with him.

Another article to consider [The Divine Name](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-teach/the-divine-name-its-use-and-its-meaning/).

Answer (score -2):

the question was "what are the different names of god in the bible and what do they mean?" However, *IN TH BIBLE* there is only ONE name for god! best identified from the tetragrammaton "YHWH" Yahweh which means "hayah asher hayah" translated "I AM THAT I AM" in Exodus 3:14. To which many bible scholars and teachers admit. This name speaks to the awesomeness of the creator's power to be self existent. Nowhere in the bible refers to the NAMES of God only NAME (singular). It has been a very common error for persons to use the creator's "TITLES" for names. Man-given titles such as god, lord, Lord God are common in the bible and the man-given name Jehovah. As someone previously posted, there is no J in the Hebrew alphabet. The name was first given in Hebrew. The letter J was not a part of the english alphabet until around the middle to late 1800s. So what was the creator's name before that time?...could not have been Jehovah.

Comment: El Shaddai is typically considered a name, and not just a title.