# Do non-christians of other religions have salvation or not beacuse they don't believe Christ is Lord?

Tags: life-of-jesus, trinity

i mean in this question that many people  don't believe he died and don't believe he is the true lord :Do other people of other religions have salvation if they do not believe in salvation by Jesus?

Comment: This is an interesting question but we stick to questions about Christianity. This question is about other religions.

Comment: Related: [Atheists and heaven](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16270/does-catholic-doctrine-teach-that-atheists-go-to-heaven-too) but that question is explicitly asked from a particular Christian perspective.

Comment: Can the experts edit? It is meant to be 'what is the Christian view? Interesting enough topic.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of several questions liked [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/what-is-the-guideline-for-near-duplicates-that-are-duplicate-by-pattern-but-not).  It is different in the details but is still in the lines of "do X not get to go to heaven just because of Y?"  feel free to browse all the answers on those question and you'll likely find that the answers to those also answer yours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to people who have never heard about Jesus?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/what-happens-to-people-who-have-never-heard-about-jesus)

Answer (score 2):

The book of Romans touches on the subject of those who do not have the law. The law itself does not make a person holy. The righteousness even being written on the heart. Their conscience bearing witness

**> God’s Righteous Judgment**

> 1You, therefore, have no excuse, you who pass judgment on someone
>   else, for at whatever point you judge another, you are condemning
>   yourself, because you who pass judgment do the same things. 2Now we
>   know that God’s judgment against those who do such things is based on
>   truth. 3So when you, a mere human being, pass judgment on them and yet
>   do the same things, do you think you will escape God’s judgment? 4Or
>   do you show contempt for the riches of his kindness, forbearance and
>   patience, not realizing that God’s kindness is intended to lead you to
>   repentance?
>
> 5But because of your stubbornness and your unrepentant heart, you are
>   storing up wrath against yourself for the day of God’s wrath, when his
>   righteous judgment will be revealed. 6God “will repay each person
>   according to what they have done.”a 7To those who by persistence in
>   doing good seek glory, honor and immortality, he will give eternal
>   life. 8But for those who are self-seeking and who reject the truth and
>   follow evil, there will be wrath and anger. 9There will be trouble and
>   distress for every human being who does evil: first for the Jew, then
>   for the Gentile; 10but glory, honor and peace for everyone who does
>   good: first for the Jew, then for the Gentile. 11For God does not show
>   favoritism.
>
> 12All who sin apart from the law will also perish apart from the law,
>   and all who sin under the law will be judged by the law. 13For it is
>   not those who hear the law who are righteous in God’s sight, but it is
>   those who obey the law who will be declared righteous. 14**(Indeed, when
>   Gentiles, who do not have the law, do by nature things required by the
>   law, they are a law for themselves, even though they do not have the
>   law. 15They show that the requirements of the law are written on their
>   hearts, their consciences also bearing witness, and their thoughts
>   sometimes accusing them and at other times even defending them.)**
>   16This will take place on the day when God judges people’s secrets
>   through Jesus Christ, as my gospel declares.
>
> **> The Jews and the Law**
>
> 17Now you, if you call yourself a Jew; if you rely on the law and
>   boast in God; 18if you know his will and approve of what is superior
>   because you are instructed by the law; 19if you are convinced that you
>   are a guide for the blind, a light for those who are in the dark, 20an
>   instructor of the foolish, a teacher of little children, because you
>   have in the law the embodiment of knowledge and truth— 21you, then,
>   who teach others, do you not teach yourself? You who preach against
>   stealing, do you steal? 22You who say that people should not commit
>   adultery, do you commit adultery? You who abhor idols, do you rob
>   temples? 23You who boast in the law, do you dishonor God by breaking
>   the law? 24As it is written: “God’s name is blasphemed among the
>   Gentiles because of you.”b
>
> 25Circumcision has value if you observe the law, but if you break the
>   law, you have become as though you had not been circumcised. 26So
>   then, if those who are not circumcised keep the law’s requirements,
>   will they not be regarded as though they were circumcised? 27The one
>   who is not circumcised physically and yet obeys the law will condemn
>   you who, even though you have thec written code and circumcision, are
>   a lawbreaker.
>
> 28A person is not a Jew who is one only outwardly, nor is circumcision
>   merely outward and physical. 29No, a person is a Jew who is one
>   inwardly; and circumcision is circumcision of the heart, by the
>   Spirit, not by the written code. Such a person’s praise is not from
>   other people, but from God.